# Random subsampling in column (r)

Tags: r

is possible to random subsample (i.e size 50) an entire column?

Input example:

```
Pa 0
Pb 0
Pc 127
Pd 0
Pe 13
Pf 39
Pg 0
Ph 113
Pi 0
```

Output example (size 50, random subsampled):

```
Pa 0
Pb 0
Pc 22
Pd 0
Pe 2
Pf 8
Pg 0
Ph 18
Pi 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In the input and output, you didn't change the 0 values.  So is it kept constant.  Try `indx <- df1$v2!=0; df1$v2[indx] <- sample(50, sum(indx), replace=FALSE)`

Comment: how about sample(df$col, 50)

Comment: @JohannesNE  It gives an error `Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'`

Comment: @akrun, it gives me the next error: Error: object 'df1' not found

Comment: @Peaceandlove `df1` is the object name.  Please check the data posted in my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
indx <- df1$v2!=0
df1$v2[indx] <- sample(50, sum(indx), replace=FALSE)
```

#### Update

For getting the subsamples based on the condition that the values should be less than the original value

```
f1 <- function(x, n){
  indx <- x!=0
  v1 <- sample(n, sum(indx), replace=TRUE)
  while(any(v1 > x[indx])){
  v1 <- sample(n, sum(indx), replace=TRUE)
  }
 x[indx] <- v1
 x}

 set.seed(24)
 f1(df1$v2, 50)
 #[1]  0  0 15  0 12 36  0 26  0
```

Or use `repeat`

```
  f2 <- function(x, n){
   indx <- x!=0
   repeat{
    v1 <- sample(n, sum(indx), replace=TRUE)
    if(all(v1 <x[indx])) break
    }
   x[indx] <- v1
   x}
 set.seed(24)
 f2(df1$v2, 50)
 #[1]  0  0 15  0 12 36  0 26  0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("Pa", "Pb", "Pc", "Pd", "Pe", "Pf", "Pg", 
"Ph", "Pi"), v2 = c(0L, 0L, 127L, 0L, 13L, 39L, 0L, 113L, 0L)), 
.Names = c("v1", 
"v2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Nice solution, but what happend if I have thousands of lines? It doesnt seem reasonable to write all the list by hand .

Comment: @Peaceandlove Did you mean by the `structrue(list` ?  It is from the `dput` output.  You read the dataset with read.table/read.csv` i.e. `df1 <- read.table('yourfile.txt', header=TRUE, sep=",")` and then `dput(df1)` gives the structure.  It is actually not needed, but I showed it here just for reproducibility.  BTW, if you try to run the dput for a big file, the output will be `huge`.

Comment: ok it outputs me the next:                                                                        Pa  0
Pb  0
Pc  28
Pd  0
Pe 16
Pf  17
Pg  0
Ph  23
Pi   0                                                                                                                       As you can see, Pe 16  is bigger than the original Pe, Pe 13. Then the subsamplig seems to doesnt work properly, subsamples must be smaller than original samples.

Comment: Furthermore, the total of the output is bigger than 50, i think that it simply takes a random number between 0-50 in each column number, this command doesnt consider the column as a whole.